Formatting images on a page with (background) lines at each image boundary
I'm trying to place a set of images of identical size (8 cm tall, 6 cm wide) edge to edge on A4 pages with small indicator lines on the outside of every image boundary.
(The result I'm looking for is a 24 cm by 18 cm block of 9 or less images with ~0.5 cm lines heading out from every image boundary, where a lack of images means images starting at the bottom right are missing but the rest is formatted correctly.)
Placing images consecutively on a page (led by a \noindent) with \includegraphics lead to small spaces in between images, which I've so far mostly removed using either \hspace or \vspace with negative values. This also depends on the margins set via geometry. How can I consistently set images edge to edge?
I've tried to create the small lines as a background through tikz by adding four lines, however the vertical lines do not match up with the image boundaries.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\imgwidth{60mm}
\def\imgheight{80mm}
\def\horizontaloffset{-1.15mm}
\def\verticaloffset{-0.325mm}

\AtBeginShipout{
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{
    \raisebox{-\height}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw (10mm + \imgwidth,-5mm) -- (10mm + \imgwidth, -10mm - 3 * \imgheight);
        \draw (10mm + 2 * \imgwidth,-5mm) -- (10mm + 2*\imgwidth, -10mm - 3 * \imgheight);
        \draw (5mm, -10 mm - \imgheight) -- (10mm + 3 * \imgwidth, -10 mm - \imgheight);
        \draw (5mm, -10 mm - 2 * \imgheight) -- (10mm + 3 * \imgwidth, -10 mm - 2 * \imgheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}  
}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{foo.png}\hspace{\horizontaloffset}
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{abc.png}\hspace{\horizontaloffset}
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{bar.png}\vspace{\verticaloffset}

\noindent
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{xyz.png}\hspace{\horizontaloffset}
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{baz.png}\hspace{\horizontaloffset}
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{nmo.png}\vspace{\verticaloffset}

\noindent
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{def.png}\hspace{\horizontaloffset}
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{pqr.png}\hspace{\horizontaloffset}
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{ghi.png}\vspace{\verticaloffset}

\end{document}


Working on it for a few more hours, I managed to find a solution (or at least something that works) without importing any packages besides graphicx and tikz:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}  % removes page numbering
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}  % removes paragraph indent (otherwise all graphics lines need \noindent)
\newcommand\pageheight{297mm}  % A4 page height
\newcommand\pagewidth{210mm}  % A4 page width
\newcommand\imgheight{80mm}  % image height
\newcommand\imgwidth{60mm}  % exact, otherwise the lines won't match up!
\newcommand\protrusion{5mm}  % length of protrusion
\newcommand\margin{10mm}  % margin size
\newcommand\halflinewidth{0.2pt}  % standard TikZ line width is 0.4pt

% background setup
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put (0mm,-\paperheight){
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \i in {1,2}{
\draw (-1.1mm+\margin-\halflinewidth+\i*\imgwidth, \pageheight-\margin-3*\imgheight-\protrusion) -- (-1.1mm+\margin-\halflinewidth+\i*\imgwidth, \pageheight-\margin-3*\imgheight); % bottom
\draw (-1.1mm+\margin-\halflinewidth+\i*\imgwidth, \pageheight-\margin) -- (-1.1mm+\margin-\halflinewidth+\i*\imgwidth, \pageheight-\margin+\protrusion); % top
\draw (-1.1mm+\margin-\protrusion-\halflinewidth,\pageheight-\margin-\i*\imgheight) -- (-1.1mm+\margin-\halflinewidth,\pageheight-\margin-\i*\imgheight); % left
\draw (-1.1mm+\margin+3*\imgwidth-\halflinewidth,\pageheight-\margin-\i*\imgheight) -- (-1.1mm+\margin+3*\imgwidth+\protrusion-\halflinewidth,\pageheight-\margin-\i*\imgheight); % right
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{foo.png}\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{abc.png}\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{bar.png}\vspace{-0.35mm}

\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{xyz.png}\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{baz.png}\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{nmo.png}\vspace{-0.35mm}

\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{def.png}\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{pqr.png}\includegraphics[height=\imgheight]{ghi.png}

\end{document}

The \includegraphics need to be in the same line to not insert any horizontal space.
By adding an empty line in between sets of three that are one line, LaTeX formats the sets as individual paragraphs instead of trying to place images outside of the page. This requires \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} or repeated \noindent such that the images actually start at the left margin.
There is still some vertical space though, which can be removed by using \vspace{-0.35mm} as 0.35mm seems to be the exact added space. (This surely is a variable similar to \parindent but I couldn't find its name.)
Now the block of images aligned to the top left margins is complete, but the lines protruding outward are missing. To create these as a constant background, \AddToHook and a tikz \foreach loop can be used.
The individual lines are defined by their relative position to the page, the images and the margin, with a magic value of -1.1mm as the origin of the TikZ background is not the exact south east, but a point ~1.1mm further inward for some reason. (A 1.1mm offset means a line at "0,0" is completely visible, which is why \halflinewidth is used to horizontally center the line at the image boundaries.)
This solution successfully fulfills my requirements of aligning properly with less than nine images, as long as all images are guaranteed to be the exact same known aspect ratio.
